# Diophantine equation $(E): 49x-6y=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We suppose the Diophantine equation on $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z} \quad$ $(E): 49x-6y=1$ and it's general solution is: $\{(6k+1),(49k+8): k\in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

We set $N = 1+7+7^2+...+7^{2007}$.

How can I prove that?

- The conjugate $(7^{2006},N)$ is a solution for the equation $(E)$.
- $N\equiv 0 \mod 4$ and $N\equiv0 \mod 503.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  If $6k+1=7^{2006}$, what is $k$?  Can you express it as the sum of a geometric series?  For the second, note $7 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$ and $503$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ x = 7^k\:\Rightarrow\:  y\, =\,\dfrac{49x-1}{6}\, =\, \dfrac{7^{k+2}-1}{7 - 1}\, =\, 7^{k+1}\!+\,\cdots + 7 + 1$